# Replicating SKAction.playSoundFileNamed() with volume?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been using playSoundFileNamed() to play a machine-gun type of sound - repeats very quickly and often has the sound overlaps. I'd like to add a volume control to it, and I can't figure out how - Since it requires a variable amount of sound effects playing over each other I have to create the audio player on the spot, and I can't find a way to preload the sound data for it that way, making it lag like crazy. SKAction.playSoundFileNamed() works perfectly, but... it doesn't have a volume option. I haven't been able to figure out a way to replicate it with volume that doesn't lag.

Answer (score 4):

Prefered method is to use `SKAudioNode` to achieve the effects you want,

but to answer the question at hand

```
let sound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("machinegun")
let action = SKAction.changeVolume(by: -1, duration: 1)
let group = SKAction.group([sound,action])

node.run(group)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417664-playsoundfilenamed